# UserControl como eliminarlo

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación de escritorio `windows form`, cuando cierro un `UserControl` lo hago de la siguiente manera.

```
private void _proveedor_ProveedorClose(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pnlPiso.Controls.Remove(_proveedor);
        dgvHelper.DataSource = null;
    }
```

Los `UserControl` que uso los llamo a un panel que me sirve de piso como el `pnlPiso`.
Pero lo curioso es que en el `UserControl` tengo una DGV cargado con 10 registros. Entonces voy a la db y manualmente elimino 5 registros, cierro el `UserControl` con el código que muestro lineas arriba y cuando vuelvo a llamar al `UserControl` me muestra en el DGV 10 registros pero si solo debe mostrar 5 registros.

Nota: el `dgvHelper` es de otro DGV que no tiene que ver con el DGV que estoy mencionando.
¿Como debo de destruir o borrar de memoria el `UserControl` para que cuando lo vuelva a llamar me muestre los datos reales?

Solo logro ver los datos reales cuando salgo del visual studio y vuelo abrir la app.

Comment: de que evento se trata el ProveedorClose ? porque lo user control no tienen ningun concepto de cerrar. cuando vuelves a mostrar el user control creas una nueva instancia usando el "new" y agregas esta a pnlPiso.Controls.Add()

Comment: El ProveedorClose es un evento que cree para cerrar el userControl y limpiar una grilla que se encuentra en el formulario MDI

Comment: Estoy trabajanbdo con Ninject var producto = CompositionRoot.Resolve<ucProducto>(); no puedo crear una nueva instancia usando new

Comment: Leandro pero tengo entendido que el ninject hace el new por debajo, que puede estar sucediendo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema que tenía era que estaba inicializando las variables de llamar a mis UserControl en el constructor del formulario MDI es por eso que se destruian. Cambie el código del constructor al evento click donde llamaba al UserControl.

```
private void btnMenuProducto_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dgvHelper.DataSource = null;
        var producto = CompositionRoot.Resolve<ucProducto>();
        this.CurrentControl = producto;
    }
```

Con esto logre solucionar el problema que tenía.

Answer (score 2):

Básicamente, puedes utilizar un ciclo **foreach** para recorrer los controles que se encuentran dentro del **Panel** (**pnlPiso**), luego llamas al método **Clear()** del panel y de este modo se eliminan las instancias creadas dentro del panel.

Tu código quedaría de este modo:

```
private void _proveedor_ProveedorClose(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dgvHelper.DataSource = null;
    foreach (Control control in pnlPiso.Controls)
    {
        control.Dispose();
    }
    pnlPiso.Controls.Clear();        
}
```

Realmente no es necesario el ciclo, pero de esta manera aseguramos que el **GC** (**Garbage Collector**) haga su trabajo prácticamente de manera instantánea.

Comment: Hola Christiam, al implementar el código que me proporcionas destruye la variable que uso llamar al UC y cuando lo llamo de nuevo ya no existe, tendría que volver a ejecutar la aplicación. Que es lo que pasa si tengo 10 registros en la db y elimino manualmente en la db 5 regtistros al momento que vuelvo a llamar a mi UC me debe mostras 5 registros ya que en el evento load mando a llenar la grilla.

Comment: Estuve depuerando el código y cuando llamo por segunda vez al UC ya no pasa por el load ese es el problema.

Comment: Como dice Leandro tendría que usara un new al momento de llamar al UC, pero estoy trabajando con ninject y la manera de llamara a mi UC es var producto = CompositionRoot.Resolve<ucProducto>(); es muy distinto a hacer Form3 frm = new Form3();

Comment: Tengo entendido que el ninject hace el new por debajo.